# Seneca amqp transport's dead letter exchange x-message-ttl

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-modules, amqp, seneca

I am updating seneca-amqp-transport npm package from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0.

I am getting below error while starting the seneca.js microservice.

*{"message":"Channel closed","stackAtStateChange":"Stack capture: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl'for queue 'seneca.add.role:worker.cmd:any' in vhost '/': received the value '60000' of type 'signedint' but current is the value '360000' of type 'signedint'"\n    at Channel.C.accept...*

What i understood with this message is x-message-ttl value is different what we are setting in the code and in the rabbitmq queue.
I checked the rabbitmq queue and there x-message-ttl time is 360000.
Also checked in code there also x-message-ttl is 360000.

```
{
          queues: {
            prefix: "seneca.add",
            separator: ".",
            options: {
              durable: true,
              arguments: {
                "x-dead-letter-exchange": "seneca.dlx",
                "x-message-ttl": 360000
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I checked change log but not getting what got changed due to which i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
In seneca-amqp-protocol version 2.2.0 they updated the con figuration option.
Update configuration options to

Old Config

```
{amqp: {
    listen: {
      channel: {
        prefetch: 1
      },
      queues: {
        prefix: "seneca.add",
        separator: ".",
        options: {
          durable: true,
          arguments: {
            "x-dead-letter-exchange": "seneca.dlx",
            "x-message-ttl": 360000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

New Config

```
{amqp: {
    listener: {
      channel: {
        prefetch: 1
      },
      queues: {
        prefix: "seneca.add",
        separator: ".",
        options: {
          durable: true,
          arguments: {
            "x-dead-letter-exchange": "seneca.dlx",
            "x-message-ttl": 360000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```